# Perform programmatic Send/Receive on Outlook that will work for 2003, 2007 and 2010

Tags: .net, outlook

I am trying to write some basic Outlook code that should support Outlook 2003, 2007 and 2010. I am working with Outlook 2010 PIAs. Everything works except a method that should cause Outlook to perform Send/Receive. I have tried a couple of options:

1. Call Namespace.SendAndReceive method (works on Outlook 2007 and 2010, fails on Outlook 2003 with AccessViolationException).
2. Iterate through Namespace.SyncObjects and calling their start method (works in Outlook 2003 and 2007 and fails on Outlook 2010 with RPC server is not available when I try to call GetNamespace("MAPI") on my application object)

Can someone propose a method that should work consistently on all versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `SendAndReceive()` was added as a convenience method in 2007 so that won't work in 2003 as you found out. According to the [2010 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860705.aspx) you should still be able to use `SyncObjects` collection and still call `Start()`. Is it possible that you're 2010 installation has a bad mail/news/whatever profile? Is `Start()` failing on a specific `SyncObject`?

The other solution which you probably already thought of is to use `SyncObjects` for 2003 and `SendAndReceive()` for future versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that my installation is problematic since I have done that a couple of times after a fresh installation. I thought about the second option, but it is ugly and I would rather not perform a hard coded test on my code. I will try to investigate which item fails and add it to my question later.

Comment: I have edited my question. The RPC server is not available exception is thrown when I try to call GetNamespace("MAPI") on the application class on Outlook 2010.

Comment: Found out that when I try to do send and receive outside of the test application it works. So I deduce that my code fails due to another bug on my application. @Chris thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First Register the Sync Event     
if (oApp.Session.SyncObjects.Count > 0)
{
    _syncObj = oApp.Session.SyncObjects[1];
    _syncObj.SyncEnd += new Outlook.SyncObjectEvents_SyncEndEventHandler(_syncObj_SyncEnd);
    _syncObj.Start();
}
void _syncObj_SyncEnd()
{
    _syncObj.Stop();
}
```